# Youtube Data v3 - How to reset subscription newItemCount

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As I remember, it is possible to reset subscription.contentDetails.newItemCount to 0 but now I can't find a way. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is only readable JSON, you can't modify the values

Comment: When I say reset I mean posting a query to Youtube data service to update the value on Google server. Just like update a video's metadata. Is it possible?